# How to plot shaded areas on a seaborn countplot

Tags: seaborn

I would like to be able to show shaded areas on a seaborn countplot as shown below. The idea would be to show the covid lockown periods that cover the data period. I have the countplot, but i cant figure out how to add the the shaded area.

My current df contains dates of properties for sale (from domain.com.au), and i have a small dataset of covid dates:

[image: covid dates]

The code that generates the seaborn plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10));
sns.countplot(data=df, x='dates', ax=ax)
```

representation of what i am looking to produce (created from excel).

[image: seaborn plot]

Comment: Could you provide a part of the properties dataset as well in the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your property dataset looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ["2022-07-01", "2022-07-01", "2022-07-01", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-03", "2022-07-04", "2022-07-05", "2022-07-05", "2022-07-05", "2022-07-06"],
    "prop": ['test'] * 11
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date

          date  prop
0   2022-07-01  test
1   2022-07-01  test
2   2022-07-01  test
3   2022-07-02  test
4   2022-07-02  test
5   2022-07-03  test
6   2022-07-04  test
7   2022-07-05  test
8   2022-07-05  test
9   2022-07-05  test
10  2022-07-06  test
```

Then you could do a bar plot of the counts and shade date ranges with matplotlib's [axvspan](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10));
prop_count = df['date'].value_counts()
plt.bar(prop_count.index, prop_count.values)
for start_date, end_date in zip(covid_df['start_date'], covid_df['end_date']):
    ax.axvspan(start_date, end_date, alpha=0.1, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of the plot]